# Unusual Results from MySql IN clause

Tags: mysql, in-clause

Here is a really strange one guys, at least to me anyways.

I have a query which retrieves some stats for the top few entities and their associated record counts over the last few months.

All works fine however it is not displaying Junes results. The query is running fine it just wont give Junes results.

If I do any of the following then things start to work again:

1. Change the IN clause to a join instead with a sub query which returns the exact same list as is used by the IN clause
2. Add the week number to the group by which should be unnecessary as I have checked and the MonthNumber is correctly resolved for the records.

But I really want to find out why this is happening rather than just patching the query. To my eyes here the query I have should work.

```
SELECT
YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(mt.`date_created`)) AS 'Year',
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(mt.`date_created`)) AS 'MonthNumber',
MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(mt.`date_created`)) AS 'MonthName',
WEEKOFYEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(mt.`date_created`) ) AS 'Week',
`at`.`group_name`,
COUNT(`mt`.`mt_id_pk`) AS 'record_count' 
FROM
`my_table` AS `mt` 
INNER JOIN `another_table` AS `at` ON `mt`.`at_id_fk` = `at`.`at_id_pk` 
WHERE `at`.`group_name` IN ('something1','something2','something3')
GROUP BY `at`.`group_name`, `MonthNumber`
HAVING  `Year` = YEAR(NOW())
ORDER BY `MonthNumber` DESC
```

Comment: You use HAVING for an aggregate function but YEAR() is not an aggregate function. COUNT or SUM for example are aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YEAR() is not an aggregate function and shoult not be use for HAVING clause it should be like instead:

```
SELECT
YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(mt.`date_created`)) AS 'Year',
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(mt.`date_created`)) AS 'MonthNumber',
MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(mt.`date_created`)) AS 'MonthName',
WEEKOFYEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(mt.`date_created`) ) AS 'Week',
`at`.`group_name`,
COUNT(`mt`.`mt_id_pk`) AS 'record_count' 
FROM
`my_table` AS `mt` 
INNER JOIN `another_table` AS `at` ON `mt`.`at_id_fk` = `at`.`at_id_pk` 
WHERE `at`.`group_name` IN ('something1','something2','something3')
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(mt.`date_created`)) = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY `at`.`group_name`, `MonthNumber`
ORDER BY `MonthNumber` DESC
```

Comment: Great stuff thanks for this. You are correct and it works now. I'm wondering though why it worked for all the other months and not June. It was successfully only retrieving records for this year using the having clause. That's unusual isn't it.

Comment: Probably since it still early in June you don't have records yet for this year that is in June?

Comment: Yeah that was my initial thought too but I do have over 400 for June in the database. Its very strange now I must say. I just checked and this was the only script that I used having in, in my other scripts I had correctly used it in a where clause, it must have something to do with the having clause.

Comment: Has it been running for about a year? Wonder if the issue is that this june is the first time you have a month which is in 2 years?

Comment: It could be because you are using HAVING clause in an unprescribed manner and/or it could also be your GROUP BY which has the MonthNumber and mySQL did not include the month of June for this year because it is not yet complete? Just a guess :-)

Comment: @Kickstart & Edper, Super that's it guys. The application turned 1 year old only yesterday. The having clause must not have been used at all until it was over one year old. Thanks a million again everyone. ;-)

Comment: Having more of a think. If there were records for the groups from June last year then the group by would get the count for the group_name and MonthNumber. However the other fields are not specified as group by fields or aggregate fields so will be taken from an unspecified row. While not certain it normally choses the first rows values, hence it is likely bringing back a Year or 2012 (despite there being figures for june for both 2012 and 2013). The HAVING clause then disposes of the row as the year is not the current one.